# 502 Bad Gateway (nginx) while running Spring Boot Application on AWS Bean Stalk Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently managing an AWS Bean Stalk Environment on which a .JAR file application has been deployed. The input variables which power up the application comes from a RDS MySQL DB as json.

Below screenshot of the log for the errorI am currently facing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaXT5.png

I tried to update the inbound security rule of the concerned EC2 instance to port 5000. Still the error persists.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCgQo.png